# Help with big array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm new to php and i'm trying to filter some words from a string, using an array, here's the array:

```
$array_lugares = array
(
array("barra"=>array
(
/*SENTIDO BARRA*/
"Sao conrado"=>array("-22.999743","-43.270694"),
"Elevado do Joa"=>array("-22.999429","-43.27317")
),
"zona sul"=>array
(
/*SENTIDO ZONA SUL:*/
"passarela da barra"=>array("-23.008346","-43.303708"),
"barra grill"=>array("-23,010576", "-43,302028"),
"lagoa barra"=>array("-22,997348", "-43,263200")
),
"recreio"=>array
(
/*SENTIDO RECREIO:*/
"passarela da barra"=>array("-23.008283","-43.303634"),
"rio mar"=>array("22.999958","-43.402648"),
"ribalta"=>array("-22,999753", "-43,409211")
)));
```

when I do:

```
foreach($array_lugares[0]['zona sul'] as $lugar){
echo $lugar;
echo "</br>";
}
```

the output is:

```
Array
Array
Array
```

how can I make it so it shows:

```
barra
zona sul 
recreio
```

in the output, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 foreach($array_lugares[0] as $k => $lugar){
   echo $k;
   echo "</br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a multidimensional array, you can loop through `$lugar;` also, and it will give you the correct output

Update:

```
foreach($array_lugares[0]['zona sul'] as $lugar){
   foreach ($lugar as $value) {
     // further inside the array

   }

 echo "</br>"; 

}
```

but i think you should revisit the code you have and see if this is really the way you want to work with your data

Answer (score 0):

that's because `$array_logares[0]['zona sul']` is giving you the object

```
array
(
/*SENTIDO ZONA SUL:*/
"passarela da barra"=>array("-23.008346","-43.303708"),
"barra grill"=>array("-23,010576", "-43,302028"),
"lagoa barra"=>array("-22,997348", "-43,263200")
)
```

and each element *is* an array (of points). If you want the names (instead of the array of points) you would do this:

```
foreach(array_keys($array_logares[0]['zona sul']) as $lugar)
```

if you want the name *and* the point, you would do this:

```
foreach($array_lugares[0] as $name => $lugar)
```